# How to call up a page or a post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a category page to show a particular page (or a post) if there no posts in the category. How it can be done?

So far, I figured out that it depends on index.php file. I created a new index.php file under the theme-child template. I can make it show plain a text message like "currently there are no posts in that category", but instead of that, I want it to render a specific page (or a post).

What I should do in that PHP file? It looks as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <?php if( pinboard_get_option( 'slider' ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'slider' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'wide' ); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'boxes' ); ?>
<?php elseif( ( is_home() && is_paged() ) || ( ! is_home() && pinboard_get_option( 'location' ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php pinboard_current_location(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="container">
    <section id="content" <?php pinboard_content_class(); ?>>
        <?php if( is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) || ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
            <?php pinboard_category_filter( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="entries">
                <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div><!-- .entries -->
            <?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_post ("page-id-2364"); ?> //this doesn't work!
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section><!-- #content -->
    <?php if( 'no-sidebars' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && 'full-width' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && ! is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) && ! ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
```

Made some changes in the code according to the article https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ but no success. :(
Definitely I miss something very fundamental here, but what?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <?php if( pinboard_get_option( 'slider' ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'slider' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'wide' ); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'boxes' ); ?>
<?php elseif( ( is_home() && is_paged() ) || ( ! is_home() && pinboard_get_option( 'location' ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php pinboard_current_location(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="container">
    <section id="content" <?php pinboard_content_class(); ?>>
        <?php if( is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) || ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
            <?php pinboard_category_filter( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="entries">
                <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div><!-- .entries -->
            <?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'page_id' => 2364 ) ); ?> //still doesn't work
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section><!-- #content -->
    <?php if( 'no-sidebars' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && 'full-width' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && ! is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) && ! ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: Can anybody tell why it doesn't work?

<?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <!-- to reset post loop cycle -->
    </div>  <!-- .entries -->
    <?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
   <?php else : ?>
   <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => 2361 ) );
   _e( '$query' ); ?> 
   <?php endif; ?>
   </section><!-- #content -->

Answer (score 0):

Category page should be displayed from `category.php` file or more specified (see: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png).

You can display some file content in your `category.php` file using `require()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But what does that mean? I not quite fluent in WordPress nor PHP. What should I change or put in index.php file above? I know it works on my category page as I tried it with just one text line instead of that string that refers to a page ID that doesn't work. Or should I copy a category.php and paste it to child-theme, and if so, what I should change or add there?

Comment: ```instead of that, I want it to render a specific page (or a post)``` - specific page is some page from WordPress or your custom php page?

Comment: It's an ordinary WP page.

Comment: OK, it's clear now. You need to use `WP_Query` to get specified page details (title, content, excerpt, image etc.). See more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll study and find out if I can figure out the working solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out where the problem. :(